# GreenPlum choosing a bad query plan in join query

Tags: join, bigdata, greenplum

Please forgive my poor English

I have two tables in greenplum(version is: **PostgreSQL 9.4.20 (Greenplum Database 6.0.0-beta.3)** )

one table is : **cookie_session**

```sql
CREATE TABLE "ods_overall_cookie"."cookie_session" (
  "site_cookie" varchar(80) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
  "createtime" timestamp(6),
  "analyse_domain_cookie" varchar(30) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
  "id" int4 NOT NULL,
  .... other fields....
) 
DISTRIBUTED by(analyse_domain_cookie)
;

CREATE INDEX "index_cookie_session_id" ON "ods_overall_cookie"."cookie_session" USING btree (
  "id" "pg_catalog"."int4_ops" ASC NULLS LAST
);

CREATE INDEX "index_analysis_domain_cookie_btree" ON "ods_overall_cookie"."cookie_session" USING btree (
  "analyse_domain_cookie" COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default" "pg_catalog"."text_ops" ASC NULLS LAST
);
```

---

and another table :**ta202202**

```sql
CREATE TABLE "ods_log"."ta202202" (
  "id" serial8,
  "uvcookie" varchar(50) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
  .... other fields ...
) distributed by (uvcookie)
;

CREATE INDEX "index_ta202202_id" ON "ods_log"."ta202202" USING btree (
  "id" "pg_catalog"."int8_ops" ASC NULLS LAST
);


CREATE INDEX "indev_ta202202_uvcookie" ON "ods_log"."ta202202" USING btree (
  "uvcookie" COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default" "pg_catalog"."text_ops" ASC NULLS LAST
);
```

The two tables have about 100 million data respectively.
My query sql is:

```sql
    select o.id,g.site_cookie 
    from ods_log.ta202201  o 
    join ods_overall_cookie.cookie_session  as g 
            on g.analyse_domain_cookie  = o.uvcookie 
    WHERE o.ID BETWEEN 20000000 and 20000077;
```

this query return in 0.14 seconds, explain ANALYZE result is:

```
Gather Motion 24:1  (slice1; segments: 24)  (cost=0.00..434.40 rows=1 width=41) (actual time=1.785..4.098 rows=552 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..434.40 rows=1 width=41) (actual time=0.225..1.948 rows=276 loops=1)
        Join Filter: true
        ->  Index Scan using index_ta202201_id on ta202201  (cost=0.00..6.02 rows=3 width=25) (actual time=0.100..0.142 rows=8 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((id >= 20000000) AND (id <= 20000077))
        ->  Index Scan using index_analysis_domain_cookie_btree on cookie_session  (cost=0.00..428.38 rows=1 width=33) (actual time=0.013..0.213 rows=34 loops=8)
              Index Cond: ((analyse_domain_cookie)::text = (ta202201.uvcookie)::text)
Planning time: 59.930 ms
  (slice0)    Executor memory: 216K bytes.
  (slice1)    Executor memory: 156K bytes avg x 24 workers, 156K bytes max (seg0).
  (slice2)    
Memory used:  128000kB
Optimizer: Pivotal Optimizer (GPORCA) version 3.39.0
Execution time: 26.725 ms
```

It seems use **Nested Loop**

But when I increase the ID range in the where condition,Even if only plus 1, like: **o.ID BETWEEN 20000000 and 20000078**,
Time consumption has become 25 seconds, increasing 200 times

```
Gather Motion 24:1  (slice1; segments: 24)  (cost=0.00..437.02 rows=1 width=41) (actual time=10266.694..23884.316 rows=557 loops=1)
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=0.00..437.02 rows=1 width=41) (actual time=12256.944..23881.566 rows=276 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: ((ta202201.uvcookie)::text = (cookie_session.analyse_domain_cookie)::text)
        Extra Text: (seg0)   Initial batch 0:
(seg0)     Wrote 874907K bytes to inner workfile.
(seg0)     Wrote 1K bytes to outer workfile.
(seg0)   Overflow batches 1..7:
(seg0)     Read 1200209K bytes from inner workfile: 171459K avg x 7 nonempty batches, 335761K max.
(seg0)     Wrote 766456K bytes to inner workfile: 127743K avg x 6 overflowing batches, 304587K max.
(seg0)     Read 1K bytes from outer workfile: 1K avg x 4 nonempty batches, 1K max.
(seg0)     Wrote 1K bytes to outer workfile.
(seg0)   Secondary Overflow batches 8..32767:
(seg0)     Read 2014970K bytes from inner workfile: 9201K avg x 219 nonempty batches, 258871K max.
(seg0)     Wrote 1573816K bytes to inner workfile: 12107K avg x 130 overflowing batches, 247277K max.
(seg0)     Read 1K bytes from outer workfile.
(seg0)   Hash chain length 4.2 avg, 4645100 max, using 3735148 of 59506688 buckets.  Skipped 32541 empty batches.
        ->  Index Scan using index_ta202201_id on ta202201  (cost=0.00..6.02 rows=4 width=25) (actual time=0.380..0.428 rows=8 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((id >= 20000000) AND (id <= 20000078))
        ->  Hash  (cost=431.00..431.00 rows=1 width=51) (actual time=12253.540..12253.540 rows=15647864 loops=1)
              ->  Seq Scan on cookie_session  (cost=0.00..431.00 rows=1 width=51) (actual time=0.058..5175.550 rows=15647865 loops=1)
Planning time: 62.416 ms
  (slice0)    Executor memory: 184K bytes.
* (slice1)    Executor memory: 245659K bytes avg x 24 workers, 375566K bytes max (seg0).  Work_mem: 290371K bytes max, 1149907K bytes wanted.
Memory used:  128000kB
Memory wanted:  1150306kB
Optimizer: Pivotal Optimizer (GPORCA) version 3.39.0
Execution time: 23927.425 ms
```

My query plain from **Nested Loop** changed to **Hash Join**,  seems greenplum choosing a bad query plan.
I continue to adjust my between condition, result is:

| from | to | plan | speed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20000000 | 20000077 | Nested Loop | Fast |
| 20000000 | 20000078 | Hash Join | Slow |
| 20000001 | 20000078 | Nested Loop | Fast |
| 20000001 | 20000079 | Hash Join | Slow |
| 20000002 | 20000079 | Nested Loop | Fast |
| 30000000 | 30000068 | Nested Loop | Fast |
| 30000000 | 30000069 | Hash Join | Slow |
| 30000001 | 30000069 | Nested Loop | Fast |

I tried:

```
 set enable_nestloop= on;
 set enable_hashjoin = off;
 set enable_mergejoin = off;
```

or change my query like :

```sql
    select xxx form a,b where a.id between xxx and xxx and a.uvcookie = b.analyse_domain_cookie
```

or change to: **left join / inner join / full join**

But things haven't changed.

So: Please help me tell me how I should adjust. I want to query the data of the table in pages according to the span of 1000 for ID field. At present, if greenplum continue to use the nested loop plan, it is obviously faster than Hash Join

Comment: Hi, Greenplum has 2 optimizers to generate plans: Postgres Legacy Planner & ORCA. From the question, you plan is generated by ORCA. So you need to tune ORCA related params to control plan. ORCA related GUCs are `optimizer_enable_xxx` like. Refer to https://github.com/greenplum-db/gpdb/blob/main/src/backend/utils/misc/guc_gp.c#L325

Comment: @kainwen Hi bor,  thanks for your answer , I turn off optimizer_enable_hashjoin and optimizer_enable_tablescan,   then it works.  This problem bothered me for two days.  Finally, thank you again

Answer (score 0):

According to kaiwen's answer, execute

```sql
SET optimizer_enable_hashjoin = OFF;
SET optimizer_enable_tablescan = OFF;
```

it works， The problem is finally solved